# Question about function of bounded variation's derivative

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, bounded-variation

$\text { Let } u_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n^{2}} e^{-n^{2} x^{2}}, x \in \mathbb{R}$

(i) Calculate Var $u_{n}$

(ii) Let $u(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_{n}(x), x \in \mathbb{R} .$ Prove that $u \in B P V(\mathbb{R})$

(iii) Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_{n}^{\prime}(x)$ does not converge uniformly in $[-1,1]$

(iv) Find a formula for $u^{\prime}$.

Well,I have solved (i) (ii).

For (iv),Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_{n}^{\prime}(x)$ does not converge uniformly in $[-1,1]$,So we can't use term by term differential theorem .OTOH, we observe that $u(x)$ is monotonous in $[-\infty,0],[0,+\infty]$,So we can use Fubini term by term differential theorem(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem_on_differentiation) in $[-n,1-n],[n-1,n]$,Then we obtain that  $u^{\prime}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_{n}^{\prime}(x) $  a.e. in $\mathbb{R}$.But we cannot find a formula of $u^{\prime} $for the whole real line in this way.

Can someone help me solve (iii) (iv)?Thanks in advance.

Comment: On any compact interval away from $0$, the series $\sum u_n'(x)$ does converge uniformly by the Weierstrass test.  So termwise differentiation is possible to find the derivative at any point $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(iii) Note that for $x \in [0,1]$,

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty u_n'(x) \right| \geqslant \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} 2xe^{-k^2x^2}\geqslant n \cdot 2xe^{-4n^2x^2},$$

and, since $\frac{1}{n} \in [0,1]$,

$$\sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty u_n'(x) \right| \geqslant n \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{1}{n}e^{-2n^2(1/n)^2}=2e^{-2}$$

Since the RHS does not converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ the Cauchy criterion is violated , and the series fails to converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ and, therefore, on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Excellent proof!

Comment: All that's left is to consider $u'(0)$.  Do you see why you can find $u'(x)$ by termwise differentiation for all $x \neq 0$.

Comment: I see that.We can choose  large enough integer $n$ so that $\frac{1}{n}\notin [a,b]$.

Comment: But how to deal with $u'(0)$?Just give me a hint.

Comment: @Johnstein: I'm still looking into that. One possible approach is to consider directly directly the limit as $h \to 0$ of $\frac{u(h)-u(0)}{h} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-n^2h^2}-1}{hn^2}$.

Comment: For example with $u_n(x) = \frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2}$, we can show that $u'(0)$ does not exist because $\frac{u(h) - u(0)}{h} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-nh}-1}{hn^2} <  \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{e^{-nh}-1}{hn^2}$.  If the derivative existed, then taking limits of both side we get $u'(0) < -\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n}$. Taking the limit as $m \to \infty$ leads to a contradiction $u'(0) < -\infty$.   Trying the same thing with $u_n(x) = \frac{e^{-n^2x^2}}{n^2}$ just gives us $u'(0) \leqslant 0$ which is inconclusive.  I suspect here that $u'(0) = 0$.